# Subquery returning more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    gh_id,
    gh_Date,
    (SELECT V_ALLAccounts.h_name
       FROM V_ALLAccounts, Tbl_Golname
      WHERE kid = gh_F_kcode
        AND mid = gh_F_mcode
        AND tid = gh_F_tcode)
  FROM Tbl_Golname, V_ALLAccounts
```

When I run that query I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Change the subquery to `SELECT TOP 1 V_ALLAccounts.h_name FROM ...`

Comment: Edit your question with sample data, desired results, and describe what you want the query to do.  Also, never use commas in the `from` clause.  Use explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, this is what you want:

```
SELECT gh_id, gh_Date,
       (SELECT V_ALLAccounts.h_name
        FROM V_ALLAccounts 
        WHERE kid = gh_F_kcode and 
              mid = gh_F_mcode and tid = gh_F_tcode
       )
FROM Tbl_Golname ;
```